# How to disable the component hierarchy in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, asp.net5

I would like to achieve a similar effect like in WPF application, where you have a XAML hierarchy and disabling one of the ancestors makes all of its children to be disabled as well.

I could not find any similar approach in Blazor components.

I tried to look into Cascading parameters and values but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Lets say I have a component hierarchy like this below:

```xml
<PanelContainer Title="Upload log file">
   <ParagraphRow ParagraphType="ParagraphType.Paragraph1" Label="Some test row">
      <EditBox Text="Some test text" />
   </ParagraphRow>
   <ParagraphRow ParagraphType="ParagraphType.Paragraph2" Label="Some fancy test row disabled" IsEnabled="false">
      <EditBox Text="Some fancy test text" />
   </ParagraphRow>
   <ParagraphRow ParagraphType="ParagraphType.Paragraph3" Label="Some other test row">
      <EditBox Text="Some disabled test text" IsEnabled="false" />
   </ParagraphRow>
</PanelContainer>
```

All the components here are inherited from a base component class where the `IsEnabled` Property is declared as a public Property.
Each component should behave different according to their `IsEnabled` value.

**For example:**
The `EditBox` should disable the inner input `HTML` tag, attach the CSS class to the wrapper tag etc.
If I just disable the `EditBox` itself it works like a charm, nothing fancy about it (third `ParagraphRow`).

I would like to get the same result with the second `ParagraphRow`, where the row itself has been disabled.  Here I would like to make some disabling logic to the `row` component (*CSS class for the label, validation logic changes and so on*), but also I would like its children (the `EditBox` in this case) also be "notified" somehow about being disabled, so it can update by itself to the disabled state.

I would prefer a solution where I don't have to throw bindings and cascading value `tags` all over the place, so it would *"just work"* out of the box.

Is it even possible in the Blazor architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [CascadingValues and Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

**In action:**

[image: Toggling value]
*Check it out at [Blazor REPL](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/clOFFRuB29TJfv9P49).*

**Simplifiying:**

The base component:

```
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; } = true;
    public string ImEnabled => IsEnabled?"Enabled":"Disabled";
}
```

Using components:

```
<PanelContainer IsEnabled="isEnabled">
  <ParagraphRow >
    <EditBox />
  </ParagraphRow>
</PanelContainer>
<button @onclick="()=>{isEnabled = !isEnabled;}" >Toggle</button>
@code {
    protected bool isEnabled = true;
}
```

PanelContainer

```
<h1>PanelContainer</h1>
<div style="padding-left:10px;">
    <CascadingValue Value="IsEnabled">
    @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsEnabled {get; set; }
}
```

ParagraphRow

```
@inherits IsEnabledComp

Rapragraph: @ImEnabled
<div style="padding-left:10px;">
    <CascadingValue Value="IsEnabled">
    @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

EditBox

```
@inherits IsEnabledComp
EditBox: @ImEnabled
```

Be free to change what you need to match to your own requirements.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm aiming for. Every component (EditBox, ParagraphRow and PanelContainer as well) should have an IsEnabled property, and can be overriden individually. The logic for enabled state would depend on how the component's own IsEnabled has been set, and what the result of the parent's state. I was thinking modifying your solution to pass the this reference down the chain so every component can access it's closest ancestor, and implement a base method for evaluating the enabled state which it can use to evaluate it's own... If it makes sense.

Comment: Your solution is working perfect with the modification I mentioned above. Passing down the this reference as CascadingValue, and evaluating state by the base method works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear from you. As I mentioned on answer _"Be free to change what you need to match to your own requirements."_ :)